# Duplicated level name: "Date", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm getting this error trying to get the mean of the day across multiple years in Python.

So I try this:

```
test = the_day.groupby([the_day.index.month, the_day.index.day]).mean()
```

my df:

```
Date
2001-01-02    0.052074
2001-01-03    0.096074
2001-01-04    0.041127
2001-01-05   -0.041127
2001-01-08    0.011386
.....
2019-01-08    0.013486
2019-01-08    0.067386
2019-01-08    0.098386
```

Answer (score 0):

I reset the index then by using `df.col_name.dt.month` and `df.col_name.dt.day`. I think it can solve your problem:

```
the_day.index.name = "time_index"
the_day = the_day.reset_index()
the_day["time_index"] = pd.to_datetime(the_day["time_index"])
the_day.groupby([the_day["time_index"].dt.month,the_day["time_index"].dt.day])["column_you_want_to_get_mean"].mean()
```

Hope it works!

Edit: Modified the answer according to the comment.

Comment: nope, I get the same error:
Duplicated level name: "index", assigned to level 1, is already used for level 0.

Comment: ok lets change the name of index, and addtry: the_day["index"] = pd.to_datetime(the_day["index"])

Comment: can you share all column names and dtypes?